# How to open GWT PopupPanel at the current mouse position?

Tags: gwt, popup, mouse

In my GWT page I have some widgets which the user can click. Then a PopupPanel opens which contains a list of buttons. Since the user usualy wants to click one of these buttons, I would like the popup to be placed somewhere near the current mouse position.

There is `PopupPanel.showRelativeTo(UIObject)`, but when my clickable widget is very wide, the popup opens too far from the current mouse position.

So how to place the PopupPanel somewhere near the current mouse position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myWidget.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {

        myPanel.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback() {

           @Override
           public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {

               myPanel.setPopupPosition(event.getClientX(), event.getClientY());

           }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I also had to adjust the position with offsetWidth and offsetHeigt, to stay inside visible area.